# How to represent the following set operation?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Given a set $Q$ and a set of ordered pairs $A=\{(a^{(1)},b^{(1)}),(a^{(2)},b^{(2)}),\dots\}$, I want to represent the union of $Q$ and the all first elements of ordered pairs in $A$, Can I write it as follows,

$$\{y| y \in Q \vee y \in \bigcup_{s \in A} s(1) \}?$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer by @ervx works fine, but if you are required to do it as one set and using set-builder notation, you can do:

$$\{ x | x \in Q \lor \exists y : (x,y) \in A\}$$

Answer (score 1):

Probably best to write something like this:
$$
Q\cup\{a\mid \exists b\text{ with } (a,b)\in A\}.
$$